# Why is my my UDO not responding in SAP B1

Tags: sapb1

We have two deployments of SAP B1: One test and one production. The UDO I created in staging is working. I click on the registered menu and the window opens. I followed the exact same steps in the production in creating the UDO, but the UDO won't open when I click on its menu.

I followed the usual steps for the UDO:

1. The UDT Master Data is created
2. The UDT Master Data Rows is created
3. The UDF for the UDT Master data Rows are created. I did not create any UDF for the UDT Master Data as the Code and Name fields are enough
4. The UDO is created based of the UDT Master Data and UDT Master Data Rows. The UDO was successfully registered as a menu item

During the process, the users were logged out. How do I get the UDO to open the window?

Answer (score 0):

The SAP Add-on license needs to be added to the user